# How to add referenced libraries to Selenium Java project in VS code?

Tags: java, selenium, visual-studio-code

In my code I have added the below in my settings.json file in the VS code java project still I don't see the referenced jar files added the project

```
"java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    "library/**/*.jar",
    "/home/username/lib/foo.jar"
]
```

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle to manage the libraries?

Comment: I'm using maven java project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click the `refresh` button then the added jar should be displayed under the option **Referenced Libraries**:

[image]

This is specified for no build tools project.

However, Maven project uses dependencies and there's a command called `Maven: Add a dependency` provided by the extension [Maven for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven), you can search needed dependencies then they will be added to `pom.xml`.

About adding customized jars to maven project, you need to install the jar to local repository:

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path\to\foo.jar '-DgroupId=com.example' -DartifactId=foo '-Dversion=1.0.0' -Dpackaging=jar
```

then add related dependency to `pom.xml`:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.example</groupId>
     <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Detailed information about mvn install please view [Apache Maven Install usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: I don't see referenced library option itself in my project

Comment: @BharathKashyap. Maven project doesn't has it, so you need to try the second way, if your jar is available in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/), then you add it from command palette as my answered described, that's okay, if your jar is customized, you need to manually execute the command `mvn install`, then add the dependency in `pom.xml`

Comment: Hey, I added the dependency in pom without mvn install and it got added under Maven dependencies not under Referenced libraries. Still it served my purpose and it works now.

Thanks